# Oracle 8i Replace Linefeed characters in CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, oracle8i

I have a CLOB which I'm trying to replace the linefeed chars in with `\r` or `\n` as appropriate. This is because I'm using SQL*Plus to export the data and it exports the linefeeds raw meaning my parser looking at the whitespace formatting of the output to determine field values does not work.

I tried the command like so:

`SELECT REPLACE(DESCRIPTION, chr(10), '\n') FROM ORDESCRIPTION;`

But I get:

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes`

Data:

```
SQL> select DESCRIPTION from ORDESCRIPTION where or_id = 'FOO/BAR/OR_000002';

DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
1)  Why don't you take this and shove it


SQL> spool off
```

The field actually contains more data as revealed by a slightly better database browser GUI:

```
1)  Why don't you take this and shove it

2)  This section is particularly crap

3)   Do something
```

Comment: There you go @Polppan

Comment: I'm not sure how replacing a line break with a fixed string of `\n` (which SQL*Plus would do; SQL Developer and maybe other clients treat `\n` as a new line character anyway) helps. Maybe enclosing the value with a delimiter (e.g. double quotes, but it would have to be something that doesn't exist within any of the values) would work too? Also you can use [`set long`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699121) to increase how much of the value SQL*Plus shows.

Comment: Incidentally, what you are doing seems to [work in 11g](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d91b/2); I don't have an 8i instance to try it on (perhaps not surprisingly). [Replace supports `clob` values now](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions153.htm) but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't in 8i, though [it did in 9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions102a.htm).

Comment: I don't think it would work @AlexPoole, as when SQL*Plus encounters the linefeed it seems to truncate the record output at that point. I figure if I can encode them with a replace then it will treat it like a long string and the likes of `set long` will be honoured.

Comment: I only see that with `set long 80`, it shows the whole thing with `set long 30000` for example. But maybe 8i behaved differently, or that setting didn't apply to `clob` values back then. (Found the [8i docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/function.htm#78610), which don't mention `clob`).

Comment: I presume upgrading your database to something a little more recent and supported isn't an option?

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use the dbms_lob package. here is an example from the [good old Ask Tom page](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1533006062995)

```
create table ORDESCRIPTION(
  or_id varchar2(255),
  DESCRIPTION clob
);
/

create or replace function lob_replace( p_lob in clob,
                                       p_what in varchar2,
                                       p_with in varchar2 )
return clob
as
    n        number;
    l_offset number := 1;
    l_lob    clob;        
    begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_lob, TRUE, dbms_lob.session ); 
    dbms_lob.copy( l_lob, p_lob, dbms_lob.getlength(p_lob), 1, 1 );
    loop
        n := dbms_lob.instr( l_lob, p_what, l_offset );
        if ( nvl(n,0) > 0 )
        then
            if ( (n+length(p_what)) < dbms_lob.getlength(l_lob) )
            then
               dbms_lob.copy( l_lob,
                              l_lob,
                              dbms_lob.getlength(l_lob),
                              n+length(p_with),
                              n+length(p_what) );
            end if;

            dbms_lob.write( l_lob, length(p_with), n, p_with );
            if ( length(p_what) > length(p_with) )
            then
                dbms_lob.trim( l_lob,
                   dbms_lob.getlength(l_lob)-(length(p_what)-length(p_with)) );
            end if;
            l_offset := l_offset + length(p_with);
        else
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return l_lob;
end;
/

insert into ORDESCRIPTION (or_id, description) values
('id001', 'hello'||chr(10)||chr(10)||'world'||chr(10));
/



declare
l_clob clob;
l_clob_replaced clob;
begin
    select DESCRIPTION into l_clob 
      from ORDESCRIPTION 
      where or_id = 'id001';
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr( l_clob, 255, 1 ));
    dbms_output.put_line('----------------');
    l_clob_replaced := lob_replace( l_clob, chr(10), '\n' );
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr( l_clob_replaced, 255, 1 ));
end;
/

select lob_replace(DESCRIPTION, chr(10), '\n')  
from ORDESCRIPTION;
```

**EDIT** fixed the SELECT in the usage example
**EDIT2** added FOR UPDATE to the SELECT statement in usage example
**EDIT3** updated source code, created the an SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a274/4

Comment: After creating the proceudre, when I try to perform your SELECT I get errors ORA-06550. Are you sure it's the correct syntax?

Comment: No, I'm not. Actually I take a glance on the SELECT and there is an obvious error in it (missing `from` keyword). On one hand, I'm sorry, I'll correct it. On the other hand, I'm very disappointed you did not correct it yourself, instead commented here. I would encourage you to be more independent.

Comment: As it turns out I did make a valid attempt to fix it, but I was left with another error: `ORA-22920: row containing the LOB value is not locked` which made me assume I had not correctly fixed it. This is the error I'm also faced with after applying your reviewed query. Detail:

`ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 381
ORA-06512: at "CCS.LOB_REPLACE", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 7`

Comment: adding `FOR UPDATE` to the select should fix ORA-22920. I have modified the SELECT in my answer accordingly.

Comment: this is working but actually updates the data - I just want to select it for output... I think we're very close but this is over my head. Can we get around the locking issue and still just select the data?

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason, I assumed you will want to update the field with the replaced value. I have modified the code to return a copy of the original clob. Please note that I have not tried it, I hope you'll be able to go along the lines and fix it in case there is a typo or something.

Comment: Well I've spent a good couple of hours trying to get this to work - the closest I have got is `invalid column name` which obviously is ridiculous in the three lines here. So I'm assuming the issue is now that the stored procedure is somehow suited to an insert/update rather than being able to return a SELECT value. I would really appreciate if you could take a final look at this for me. Upvote now, accept later? :D

Comment: OK, I have created an SQLFiddle to be able to try the code. I hope this will help you get this straight. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a274/4

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE works with VARCHAR2s not with CLOBs. Imagine that a single CLOB "file" had 177 TB (which is maximum CLOB size). What would Oracle do with that? Where it will store the result?

Look at procedure `DBMS_LOB.FRAGMENT_REPLACE`.

Comment: `replace` has worked with `clob` since 9i, which doesn't help the OP; but in 8i, [`dbms_lob.fragment_replace` didn't exist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76936/dbms_lo2.htm#998404).

Comment: @Alex I did not know - thx for pointing that. I thought that implicit conversion from CLOB to VARCHAR2 takes place - which is dangerous because it seems to work on sample data.